# Display an product rating in Google search results

Tags: google-search, microdata, rating, review, google-rich-snippets

i was trying to get ratings in google search result, below html i am using for aggregate rating

but still I am not getting ratings in google search results.

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="title">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="description">
        <meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content="title" />
        <meta itemprop="rating" content="4.52" />
        <meta itemprop="votes" content="44" />
    </div>
```

Comment: you did not give a minimum or maximum rating value either

Answer (score 0):

Google never guarantees that a Rich Snippets gets shown for your document, even if everything’s correct.

But you might have more luck following Google’s documentation, which uses Schema.org (not Data-Vocabulary.org, which is no longer maintained):

- [Aggregate Ratings Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#aggregate_ratings)
- [Products Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products)

Answer (score 0):

To display ratings in google search results. Go to data highlighter in search console and click on search appearances. Click on data highlighter add a URL of your website.Here i am adding https://www.hibachi.in/product-category/chicken/ URL. 
[data highlighter to show ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U68j.jpg)
Select all the fields like name, product, image,product rating etc. If you dint find rating in your site. Install any rating plugin or insert the code. Then try once. Click on publish. Google will take some time to highlight your ratings in search results.